# How to lose focus from textbox on action?

Tags: angularjs, textbox

I have a problem when user hit enter I get popup and dark background, but focus still stay on textbox and its blink so its visible and when user hit outside box it stops(lose focus).

I want to lose focus from textbox when user get popup on click or on enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `directive` to force the `blur` event to be fired, as follow:

```
myApp.directive('blurOnEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('keydown keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                elem.blur();
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Then you'll just have to set the directive in your textbox:

```
<input type="text" blur-on-enter>
```

See working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nq6fgse1/

Comment: Try again, the jsFiddle didn't save my modifications. It should be ok now :)